# Unable to install the jupyter module with pip

Tags: python, pip, jupyter

I would like to be able to install the python module jupyter with pip but I get an error in my terminal when I try 'pip install jupyter' which returns this:
`

```
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
      C:\Users\nunes\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dofs9qdx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py:265: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'cffi_modules'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running egg_info
      writing pyzmq.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to pyzmq.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to pyzmq.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to pyzmq.egg-info\top_level.txt
      running configure
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

`

I have installed Microsoft Visual Studio Builds Tools as indicated but still the same error.
If someone has an idea I'm a taker thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Try `pip install jupyterlab`.

Refer for more info: https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html

I also see that you are having an error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required

You can also try installing/upgrading Microsoft Visual C++